# how to share .env values from root component project to mutiple reusable npm installed components

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, vue.js

In react and vuejs node projects i designed lately , i have .env variables with API urls to micro services and other configuration variables i can use in root project.

But in a child component installed using npm , i  am not able to access these.

I know we can use props to pass the required data while using a child component but is there any other way we can share .env from root project to mutiple reusable npm installed components from one centralized place?

```
        // contents of .env 

    REACT_APP_API_KEY = 'my-secret-api-key'

    or 

    VUE_APP_API_KEY = 'my-secret-api-key'
```

Comment: Do you use docker-compose?

Comment: yes, our production setup has docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using docker-compose on your setup, what you can do is define the .env file to be used by each service.
Your docker-compose.yaml may look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service1:
    build: .
  env_file:                    # Add this to all services defined in yaml
      - <path-to-file>/.env    # Add this to all services defined in yaml
...
```

`<path-to-file>` should be relative to the location of the docker-compose.yaml.